# sql transaction not working after updating to .Net core 3.1 with InsightDb

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I needed to execute some stored procs in transactions using insightDb, I did the following and it was working fine with .net Core 2.2

```
        using (var ts = TransactionScopeBuilder.CreateReadCommitted())
         {
             await _profile.createProfile(user);
             await _profile.addAdditionalData(user);
             ts.Complete();
         }
```

After updating to .net core 3.1. I am getting this exception on createProfile(user). I am using insightDb and createProfile is the name of stored procedure being called. It was working fine on .net core 2.2. Here are all the details of exception.

InsightDb version is 6.3.1.

Exception:
On createProfile call I get following exception:

[image]

**SerializationStackTraceString**:
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.Implementation.SqlClientDiagnostics.SqlClientDiagnosticSourceListener.ConfigureExceptionTelemetry(DependencyTelemetry telemetry, Exception exception, PropertyFetcher numberFetcher)

**Source**:
Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector

**StackTrace**
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.Implementation.SqlClientDiagnostics.SqlClientDiagnosticSourceListener.ConfigureExceptionTelemetry(DependencyTelemetry telemetry, Exception exception, PropertyFetcher numberFetcher

**_message**
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately no :( we had to remove transaction and add try-catch.